# A triangle is a compact set

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, analytic-geometry

Let's fix a triangle

$\Delta=\{t_1x_1+t_2x_2+t_3x_3 \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid t_1,t_2,t_3 \ge 0 \quad \land \quad t_1+t_2+t_3=1\}$

of fixed vertices $x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

I want to show that $\Delta$ is compact in the plane. That's my attempt (the metric used here is the euclidean one, of course):

Let's define $f\colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \mid f(t_1,t_2,t_3)=t_1x_1+t_2x_2+t_3x_3$,

$g\colon \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R} \mid g(t_1,t_2,t_3)=t_1+t_2+t_3$.

Obviously $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions.

So the set:

$K=g^{-1}(\{1\}) \cap \{(t_1,t_2,t_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid t_1,t_2,t_3 \ge 0\}$

is closed, being the intersection of two closed sets.

Moreover:

$\forall \,(t_1,t_2,t_3) \in K \quad \|(t_1,t_2,t_3)-(0,0,0)\|=\sqrt{t_1^2+t_2^2+t_3^2} \le t_1+t_2+t_3=1<2$

so that $K$ is also bounded.

So $K$ is compact, and thus $\Delta=f(K)$ is compact by Weierstrass theorem.

Is it correct? Is there a easier (elementary) way to prove it? Thank you!

Comment: If you are open to using the Heine-Borel theorem, then $\Delta$ is both closed (as its complement is open) and bounded. Hence, it must be compact by the Heine-Borel theorem.

Comment: Ok, but how can I show that the complement of $\Delta$ is open?

Comment: You must prove that every point in the complement lies in an open disc. Given any such point you must prove that the distance from such a point to $\Delta$ is positive. Then you can find a disc whose radius is half that distance centered at the point. I am sure that any bounded closed curve in the plane is compact. You may want to consider the cases of a point inside and outside the triangle separately.

Comment: Your proof seems to be correct!

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually I think that verify that the complement of $\Delta$ is an open set is as "difficoult" as directly showing that $\Delta$ is a closed set.

Comment: Can you define a continuous mapping from $[0,1]$ into ${\bf{R^2}}$ whose image is the triangle? Divide the closed unit interval into three equal segments, map each segment to a side ensuring that $0$ and $1$ have the same value. Then, the triangle being the image of a compact interval under a continuous mapping must be compact.

Comment: This way we only show that the boundary $\partial\Delta$ is compact, not the triangle $\Delta$ itself.

Comment: No problem! Yes, with the word triangle I mean $\Delta=\{t_1x_1+t_2x_2+t_3x_3 \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid t_1,t_2,t_3 \ge 0 \quad \land \quad t_1+t_2+t_3=1\}$, and not its boundary $\partial\Delta$.

Comment: The set of points in ${\bf {R^3}}$ with non-negative coordinates which add to $1$ is closed (the inverse image of $\{1\}$ under the linear map that adds the coordinates together, and bounded (each coordinate lies in $[0,1]$), hence compact. $\Delta$ is the image of this compact set under the linear (hence continuous) map ${(t_1,t_2,t_3)} \rightarrow{t_1{x_1}+t_2{x_2}+t_3{x_3}}$ and is therefore compact.

Comment: Which is in fact my proof.

Comment: I agree! Very minor differences in the proofs-perhaps too minor to bother with. I think your proof is the simplest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method works, though I am not sure which theorem you have in mind when you say "by Weierstrass theorem." The image of a compact set under a continuous function is compact, so the triangle is compact, like you showed.

Can you prove that the line segment in $\mathbb R^2$ joining two points $P$ and $Q$ is closed? If so, then you have a direct proof that triangles (in fact any polygons) are closed, being a union of a finite number of such segments.

Comment: But if I prove the fact that the segment $PQ$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then I have only proved that the boundary of $\Delta$ is closed, not $\Delta$ itself. Thank you!